# Should I setup an OAuth2 Server?

Tags: php, lumen, oauth-2.0, oauth2-server

I'm working on a project where I'm developing a platform. As a solo-developer I made the decision to use Lumen as a PHP back-end and create an RESTful API.

Web shops should be able to install a plugin so they can access the API without having to code themselves.

I need to keep track of the web shops that use the API. I just need the same way to retrieve access tokens like Twitter and Facebook do when you register an app.

So I was thinking about OAuth2 Server but I have never used it before so I'm not sure if I'm on the right path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your own OAuth2 system then yes you will need a server running it.

The idea of OAuth2 is to authenticate your clients where a shop equals one client.

OAuth2 is not about individual users but clients. With that idea in mind you can setup an OAuth2 server and its only job would be to authenticate each request, make sure it belongs to a recognized client and then issue a token.

With that token you can then go on and issue more requests to actually interact with the system you are building. This is a very high level view of the entire system, of course.

There can be multiple variations on this, how tokens are issued, what type they 
are etc. I prefer JWT ( JSON Web Tokens ) as it's JSON and thus lightweight.

A quick search revealed this: http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/

I do have my own article on building your own OAuth2 system, however it is based on dot net not PHP. You are welcome to use it though maybe it will help clarify the concept.

Here's the link : https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/